# Have file Names to appear below image preview form

Tags: jquery

I have the following image preview script that I am currently working with I found online which works fine in the form I have created. However, I would like to modify the script in the following (attempts have been made but no success)

1.I would like to be able to have the name of the file(s) to appear. Currently, I am able to grab the name of one file. However, when uploading multiple images, the last image name is used for all images uploaded.

2.I would like to able to add a "Remove all images" button when the user has more then one image uploaded to the form.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
/*Upload Image and Preview in form*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
        $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
            var files = e.target.files,
            filesLength = files.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
                var f = files[i]
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
                    var file = e.target;
                    $("<div class=\"pip\">" +
                    "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" + 
                    "<br />" + "<span class=\"fontImage\">" + f.name + "</span><br/><span class=\"remove\">x</span>" + "</div>").insertAfter("#files");
                    $(".remove").on('click', function(){
                        $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
                        $('#files').val('');
                    });
                });

                /*if (filesLength > 1){
                    fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
                    $( "<div class=\"pip\">" + "<span class=\"removeAll\">" + "Remove All Images</span></div></div>");
                        $(".removeAll").on('click', function(){
                            $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
                            $('#files').val('');
                        });
                    });
                }*/
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
            }
            /*if(filesLength > 1){
                fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
                    $( "<div class=\"pip\">" + "<span class=\"removeAll\">" + "Remove All Images</span></div></div>").insertAfter("#files");
                    $(".removeAll").on('click', function(){
                            $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
                            $('#files').val('');
                        });
                });
            filesLength--;
            }*/
        });
    } 
    /*else {
        //alert("Your browser doesn't support to File API.");
    }*/
});
/***********************/
```

Comment: not sure but i think you can crop file name from e.target.result, as i think f.name will not work obviously as this will give you file name uploaded in last

Comment: @Farhan I tried it. Didnt work on my end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution that utilizes an IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression).  By using an IIFE, you are creating a new scope, thus, the refernce for `j` will not be updated by future iterations of the `for` loop. `FileReader`  is asynchronous, your variable `i` is being overwritten before `FileReader` has completed.

```
$("#files").on("change", function(e) {

  var files = e.target.files,
    filesLength = files.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {

    (function (j) {

      var f = files[j];
      var fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.fileName = files[j].name;
      fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
        var file = e.target;
        $("<div class=\"pip\">" +
          "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
          "<br />" + "<span class=\"fontImage\">" + file.fileName + "</span><br/><span class=\"remove\">x</span>" + "</div>").insertAfter("#files");
        $(".remove").on('click', function(){
          $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
          $('#files').val('');
        });
      });

      fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);

    })(i);

  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding file name to FileReader Object will give you file name in target, hope this will help you. Also delete button will appear when there will be more then one image and hide respectively.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="files" multiple="multiple" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#ccc;" />
<input type="button" value="Delete All" id="delete_all" style="display:none;"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#delete_all").click(function(){
        $(".pip").remove();
        $("#delete_all").hide();
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".remove", function(){
        if($(".pip").length > 1)
            $("#delete_all").show();
        else
            $("#delete_all").hide();
    });
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
        $("#files").on("change", function(a) {
            var files = a.target.files,
            filesLength = files.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
                var f = files[i]
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.fileName = files[i].name;
                fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
                    var file = e.target;
                    $("<div class=\"pip\">" +
                    "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" + 
                    "<br />" + "<span class=\"fontImage\">" + file.fileName + "</span><br/><span class=\"remove\">x</span>" + "</div>").insertAfter("#files");
                    $(".remove").on('click', function(){
                        $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
                        $('#files').val('');
                    });
                    if($(".pip").length > 1)
                        $("#delete_all").show();
                    else
                        $("#delete_all").hide();
                });             
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
            }

       });
    } 
});
</script>
```